# how to clean up the coro thread, when coro.with_timeout function timeout's in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-3.x

How should I know, when the coro.with_timeout function timeout's .how should we check thread properly cleaning up once timeout. How can I check is coro thread is cleanup job?

Is there any function to clear the thread once thread timeouts ?

Comment: please read [mcve] and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.